# simd_quatF to euler angle

Tags: swift, quaternions, euler-angles

Im trying to convert my quats to euler, but out of x/y/z components, only my X has accurate value and y/z is incorrect :- ( can any1 have a look/help ?

```
func quatToEulerAngles(_ quat: simd_quatf) -> SIMD3<Double>{
    
    
    var angles = SIMD3<Double>();
    let qfloat = quat.vector
    let q = SIMD4<Double>(Double(qfloat.x),Double(qfloat.y),Double(qfloat.z), Double(qfloat.w))
    // roll (x-axis rotation)
    
    let sinr_cosp : Double = 2.0 * (q.w * q.x + q.y * q.z);
    let cosr_cosp : Double = 1.0 - 2.0 * (q.x * q.x + q.y * q.y);
    angles.x = atan2(sinr_cosp, cosr_cosp);
    
    // pitch (y-axis rotation)
    let sinp : Double = 2 * (q.w * q.y - q.z * q.x);
    if (abs(sinp) >= 1){
        angles.y = copysign(Double.pi / 2, sinp); // use 90 degrees if out of range
    }
    else{
        angles.y = asin(sinp);
    }
    // yaw (z-axis rotation)
    let siny_cosp : Double = 2 * (q.w * q.z + q.x * q.y);
    let cosy_cosp : Double = 1 - 2 * (q.y * q.y + q.z * q.z);
    angles.z = atan2(siny_cosp, cosy_cosp);
    
    return angles;
}
```

Wiki example converted to swifht.
TIA

Answer (score 4):

My solution would be to let the (SceneKit) library do it:

```
func quatToEulerAngles(_ quat: simd_quatf) -> SIMD3<Float>{
    let n = SCNNode()
    n.simdOrientation = quat
    return n.simdEulerAngles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at and converted it to Swift,

https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToEuler/

It works for me.

```
func quatToEulerAngles(_ quat: simd_quatf) -> SIMD3<Float>{

var angles = SIMD3<Float>();
let qfloat = quat.vector

// heading = x, attitude = y, bank = z

let test = qfloat.x*qfloat.y + qfloat.z*qfloat.w;

if (test > 0.499) { // singularity at north pole
    
    angles.x = 2 * atan2(qfloat.x,qfloat.w)
    angles.y = (.pi / 2)
    angles.z = 0
    return  angles
}
if (test < -0.499) { // singularity at south pole
    angles.x = -2 * atan2(qfloat.x,qfloat.w)
    angles.y = -(.pi / 2)
    angles.z = 0
    return angles
}


let sqx = qfloat.x*qfloat.x;
let sqy = qfloat.y*qfloat.y;
let sqz = qfloat.z*qfloat.z;
angles.x = atan2(2*qfloat.y*qfloat.w-2*qfloat.x*qfloat.z , 1 - 2*sqy - 2*sqz)
angles.y = asin(2*test)
angles.z = atan2(2*qfloat.x*qfloat.w-2*qfloat.y*qfloat.z , 1 - 2*sqx - 2*sqz)

return angles
```

}